# expireAfterSeconds what timezone is used?

Tags: mongodb

When I'm doing:

```
db.events.ensureIndex({ "expiresAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 })
```

What timezone the `expiresAt` is comparing to ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB dates are UTC [dates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date). Therefore, the only values you can st the "expiresAt" field would be UTC times. And the expiry is going to be at after your set expiryAfterSeconds (in your case 0) passed since your expiresAt in UTC time.